# Date toIsoString PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want to have a date like new Date().toISOString() of javascript

The output is `2018-06-11T08:30:25.597Z`

I tried with

```
(new \DateTime('now',new \DateTimeZone("UTC")))->format(\DateTime::ISO8601) // 2018-06-12T08:21:13+0000


$t = date('c', strtotime('2010-12-30 23:21:46')); //2010-12-30T23:21:46+01:00
$t2 = date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime('2010-12-30 23:21:46')); //2010-12-30T23:21:46+01:00

$datetime = new \DateTime('2010-12-30 23:21:46');
$t3 = $datetime->format(\DateTime::ATOM); // 2010-12-30T23:21:46+01:00
```

I want to combine

> Combined ISO 8601 date and time in UTC (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:S+Timezone Offset|Z, i.e., 2018-04-18T11:02:05.261Z)

In Javascript I can have this format with

```
new Date().toISOString() //2018-06-12T08:24:49.321Z
```

Comment: Why would you need `Z` at the end? `+00:00` is also valid ISO8601 format...

Comment: Try "Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v\Z"

Comment: u can use this bro 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v\Z', it is work for me

2022-06-17T12:07:30.000Z

Answer (score 1):

Your first try is almost what you need, just change `\DateTime::ISO8601` to `\DateTime::ATOM`.

From PHP manual:

> DateTime::ISO8601
>   DATE_ISO8601
>
> ISO-8601 (example: 2005-08-15T15:52:01+0000)
>
> Note: This format is not compatible with ISO-8601, but is left this way for backward compatibility reasons. Use DateTime::ATOM or DATE_ATOM for compatibility with ISO-8601 instead.

Comment: with `(new \DateTime('now',new \DateTimeZone("UTC")))->format(\DateTime::ATOM);` I have `2018-06-12T08:37:38+00:00` But I want `2018-06-11T08:30:25.597Z`

Comment: If you need "Z" as timezone identifier, there is no way, just  `str_relpace( "+00:00", "Z", $date);` PHP haven't "Z" timezone identifier format. If you need fraction of second, then starting from `PHP 7.0` you can use `\DateTime::RFC3339_EXTENDED` or format string: `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP` in any PHP version.

Comment: `$a = (new \DateTime('now',new \DateTimeZone("UTC")))->format(\DateTime::ATOM);
        $b = str_replace( "+00:00", "Z", $a); // 2018-06-12T08:53:02Z`

Comment: @monkeyUser: there is a simpler solution: `echo (new \DateTime('UTC'))->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');`